# SonataAdmin How to display list view of children in show view of parent

Tags: php, symfony4, sonata-admin

I'm developing an interface based on Symfony 4 and Sonata Admin. I have an entity WorkSheet where I have general information and I have a list of sub Entities (OneToMany).
I can't find anywhere and I would like to know if it's possible to do so. I would like instead of displaying a list of names, display an array with multiple columns like in the Sonata Admin List view interface.

Thank you for your help :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSLww.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in the show view, only in the form view.

What you can do is to create a custom template that extends from `SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_show_field.html.twig` and override the `field_value` block.

Then in `configureShowFields`:

```
->add('services', null, [
    'template' => 'path/to/your_template.html.twig',
])
```